# How to disable auto focus of opened Windows applications?

Tags: windows

Often, when I open an application in Windows XP, it takes so long to load that I start using another application that is already open, start typing, then when the application I was trying to open finally does open it then takes my focus away and I lose a large chunk of what I was typing.

Is there any way to disable the auto focus that occurs when you open an application in Windows? Please say yes and how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing applications from stealing focus](http://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Power Toys for Windows XP, a free download for TweakUI from Microsoft lets you tweak some settings of the Windows UI, including one to “Prevent applications from stealing focus”:

Check “Prevent applications from stealing focus” to prevent applications from stealing focus from the window you are working in. Instead, their taskbar icon will flash to indicate that the application is trying to get your attention.

Try and see more...

[PowerToys](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx)

Comment: Does not work for Windows 7

Comment: this feature is not parameterized with the version 7. it is built in.

Comment: evowinds: if it's built in then... well... it doesn't work :p Are our expectations as users too high or MS just doesn't care.

Comment: @PiotrOwsiak: MS doesn't care.  They have no competition.