# Windows, never "lose focus" of the current window

Tags: windows, user-experience

I want the task bar to light up orange and never lose focus to anything. If I'm installing something and then go play a game at some point it will drop out to the finished instillation. Also, if installing multiple programs at once my 'next' button can all of sudden become "click here to install this crappy toolbar" of another program's install. Of course there are settings for some programs to not "lose focus" or "stay on top" but I really want windows to handle it. If its somehow an exe called say, Taskswtich.exe, I could possibly use Process Blocker however I'm assuming its part of a function call or some such.

For XP I found this: [How to disable auto focus of opened Windows applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/138648/how-to-disable-auto-focus-of-opened-windows-applications) but what about Windows7?

And this old post [Preventing applications from stealing focus](https://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus) with a bunch of long answers that say "no". I'd appreciate this not being merged with a 4 year old question. I'd like to avoid 3rd party software. This is 2014, don't we know how to hack windows yet?

Comment: :)  We do know how, but it's not rewarding since when you get done, you just have a fancy hack... with solitaire and notepad.  There are better things out there to play with.  (Not Being snotty can garner answers too).  Hack it yourself!  This is 2014, don't _you_ know how?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, in your Mouse Control Panel, under Pointer Options, you should uncheck the "Automatically move pointer to the default button in a dialog box". This will prevent your mouse from suddenly jumping to an unexpected location milliseconds before you click.