# Windows 7: Disable applications stealing focus

Tags: windows-7, focus

Is there any way to prevent specific programs from stealing window focus in Windows 7?

**Windows 7 doesn't have the option of using PowerToys' TweakUI**, which has been suggested in the past for stopping window focus stealing.