# Prevent Focus-Stealing from any PopUp Window

Tags: windows, windows-xp, focus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7: Disable applications stealing focus](https://superuser.com/questions/199821/Windows-7-disable-applications-stealing-focus)

I have a really annoying behavior on my Windows XP System. Any PopUp Windows (e.g. asking me for my network signin) automatically steal the focus and I end up typing half of my last line of code into the username-field of the message box.

Since I have no chance to prevent the message boxes themselve, I **really** would like to prevent the focus change!

I searched the web and here too, but the only valid answers use TweakUI and some registry entries. None of them work. I guess, its because they prevent focus stealing from another application and not from within the active application itself.

Anyone out there who knows a solution to this?

Comment: I don't understand the closing... i expicitly stated i searched and found other questions "alike" this one; including TweakUI and the registry entry which do NOT work for me! ... By the way, the other question now linked here is a "solution" for another problem (stealing focus from another app) ... well, "thanks" anyway...

Comment: I would also like to know this.