# Bluetooth "Receiving" window stealing focus on Windows 8.1

Tags: bluetooth, windows-8.1, window-focus

I am new to Windows as a daily OS at home, having been an OSX user for the past 8 years. The current most irritating thing at the moment is the Bluetooth "Receiving" window/dialog stealing focus and popping every time a new file transfer starts! If there's something running in a maximised window (I usually run Firefox like this) it will pop to foreground! Is there any way I can stop this?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if it will work but I think if you set the current Window to be always on Top, when a new window pops up you will not loose the focus (and the new windows will not pop to foreground). If you are interested in such solution I may go more into detail.

Comment: If I understand it correctly this wouldn't work for me. I still wish to switch between windows while BT transfer is happening. Setting one window to be on top will make this a pain or impractical. That window I set to be always on top will just get in the way. Or did I not understand you correctly?

Comment: No you still can switch the windows with Alt + Tab quickly. It is just that the Windows you set as Always on Top won't loose focus. When something pops up it won't come to foreground. But I did not test that so you will have to test and see if it works like that.

Comment: I realise `Alt + Tab` will still be an option, but the new window I have just switched to will be at least partially hidden by the one set to always be on top, right? I also don't see this as an option in Firefox, but there seem to be apps that I can install to add this functionality.

Comment: You can always minimize the window which is Always on Top, then nothing will be partially hidden.

Comment: This has been asked many times: [\[1\]](http://goo.gl/RJG8vY)[\[2\]](http://goo.gl/z07nCb)[\[3\]](http://goo.gl/yoICJk)[\[4\]](http://goo.gl/QEwIfN)[\[5\]](http://goo.gl/faAjf6)

Answer (score 0):

Here's How:

1. Click on Start and then Run.
2. In the text box in the Run window, type regedit and click OK. This
   will open the Registry Editor program.
3. Locate the HKEY_CURRENT_USER folder under My Computer and click on
   the (+) sign next the folder name to expand the folder.
4. Continue to expand folders until you reach the
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel registry key.
5. Select the Desktop key under Control Panel.
6. On the right-hand side of the screen, locate and double-click on the
   ForegroundLockTimeout DWORD.
7. In the Edit DWORD Value window that appears, set the Value data:
   field to 30d40. Note: Make sure the Base option is set to Hexadecimal when entering
   the DWORD value.
8. Click OK and then close Registry Editor.
9. Reboot your PC for the changes you made to take effect.

From this point forward, programs should no longer steal the focus from the window that you're currently working in.

Source: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsxp/ht/stealingfocus02.htm

Comment: Also check this SU question: http://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I have noticed various comments on this particular suggested solution mentioned it doesn't work on Windows 7. Evidently it doesn't work on Windows 8.x either!