# When starting an application (Chrome) in Windows 7/8 it is not always in focus

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, google-chrome, focus, application-launch

The last half year (or more?) I have experienced that when I launch an application, it is not always in focus/active. For example I start Chrome several hundred times per day and maybe 30% of the time Chrome is not active when I launch it. Sometimes the new Chrome window is idling within the taskbar and my last active application is in front (eg. Outlook). Other times it starts Chrome up with the window in front but it is not active and I then need to click in the new Chrome window with my mouse before it is active.

I have tried to set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundLockTimeout=0` but with same result (it was set to `30d40`).

Do note that this is not only Chrome but any(?) application. I also experience this on other computers (Win7+8) and it is getting really frustrating as I want to avoid as much mouse work as possible. I am not 100% sure on the half year time frame but for sure this was not an issue for more than a year ago so this is somehow a "new" behaviour in Windows.

Has anyone else experienced this?

I want my launched application to always be in front and active. Is there a cure for this aggravating behaviour?

Comment: It will happen with any application (chrome is typical) that has a long startup time and some other application "steals" the focus in the meantime. There are some workarounds in [Preventing applications from stealing focus](http://superuser.com/q/18383)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing applications from stealing focus](http://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus)

Comment: There is nothing in the linked thread that helps me fixing this in Win7/8