# Programs won't have focus when opened

Tags: windows-7, window-focus

Whenever I open any program on my laptop, the program opens up without focus.  I have to click the program window in order to gain focus.  If I have another window open already, the new window will open behind the existing one.  This happens with every program that I've tried, whether or not I have anything else open at the time.

Some programs that this happens with:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Notepad++
- Pidgin
- Full-screen video games

The only time I don't see this problem is when I open up a Windows folder.  Those open up with focus just fine.  How can I make it so all programs automatically get focus when I open them?

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 32-bit.  The laptop is a Dell Inspiron 1501.

Comment: did you try fixing your Aero? here: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting\Appearance and Personalization`

Comment: I have now.  It didn't seem to do anything.  The problem is still occurring.

Comment: which laptop you are using?

Comment: look at this question: http://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus

Comment: You may get some help from this link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/applications-stealing-focus-reg-key-no-longer/4ee5be7d-31ef-493b-b092-f6f6139f99cd

Comment: I've looked at those links, and neither helps me.  The answers to the SE question either don't work in Windows 7 (TweakUI) or involve changing my computer in ways that I really don't want (focus follows mouse).  The Microsoft Answers link doesn't help either; there doesn't seem to be a particular process that's ramping up usage when the bug occurs.