# Is it possible in Windows 10 to prevent an opening application from stealing focus?

Tags: windows, windows-10

In Linux I can do this but can you do this in Windows?

I launch a new application and it takes awhile to load. In the mean time I am tying text in an application or searching for an application in classic shell. While typing the launching application finally takes focus and interrupts my typing. Is there a way to prevent this in windows?

I did see this [Preventing applications from stealing focus](https://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus) but that was back pre Windows 8.x days. Does anyone know since the newer OSes that this has become possible?

Comment: There are many 3rd party program that could provide us with this ability, here a link to another forum that explain it (https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/122077-turn-off-focus-stealing.html).  Here some of it Actual Windows Manager (https://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/), Turbo Top (https://www.savardsoftware.com/turbotop/), DeskPins (https://efotinis.neocities.org/deskpins/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

1. Start the Registry Editor (Start button + R, then type regedit)
2. Search for HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundLockTimeout
3. Change the value from 0 to 30d40
4. Save and restart the computer

> (…) it does not stop 100% of applications from stealing focus, it's
>   considerably better.

Source:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c22363e5-802c-4f43-b4e3-8a7259865648/windows-10-stop-any-application-from-stealing-focus-ever-is-it-possible?forum=win10itprogeneral#123b4fea-0a57-491d-bdfa-a5ee0771f2de

Comment: Recent Windows 10 versions have the magic value of 20000 in `ForegroundLockTimeout`, but I don't really see any difference in behaviour. macOS and Linux handle this so much better.

Comment: It's already 0x00030d40.

Comment: Doesn't work, sadly enough. I'm not sure this actually was in XP but it definitely was in W2k. I remember being upset when this setting stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no built-in way to do this but [TurboTop](https://www.savardsoftware.com/turbotop/index.asp) (free as in beer) works OK for me. It allows you to tick several programs that you want to be kept on top. While that may sound paradoxical, those programs respect each other but ignore everything else. At least most of the time.