# Preventing applications from stealing focus in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, window-focus

There is a [dated question](https://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus) asking for a solution for windows 7. I have recently grew tired of newly launched applications to steal focus from my currently opened window. Is there a way how to prevent programs from stealing focus in Windows 10?

Thank you

Comment: Most of the answers to the duplicate question, which are applicable to Windows 7, are still applicable for Windows 10.  In the end, "Please understand that there is no way in which Windows can totally block applications from stealing the focus and remain functional.", applies to all versions of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound even 8 years later? omg

Comment: @rluks How Win32 works hasn't changed in those 8 years.

Comment: If you'd like newer/different answers on the existing question please [place a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing question, instead of just asking it again.